# how do you disable sorting in Numbers app?

Tags: numbers

I created a document, entered data like:

```
abc | 1
xyz | 4
ghi | 2
```

...

Then I sorted by name...

```
abc | 1
ghi | 2
xyz | 4
```

...  then I said, ok cool..  I want to temporarily turn off sorting so I can go back to the original order I had entered things in...

and........  I clicked the trash can by the sort... and the list stayed sorted.

how do I turn the sort off?

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'restore order before sorting' (except limited possibility of undo already mentioned) but there is [restore previous version of file](https://support.apple.com/guide/numbers/restore-an-earlier-version-of-a-spreadsheet-tan7f1de6ec5/mac)

> Every time you save a spreadsheet, Numbers saves it as a new version.
> As a result, you can browse earlier versions, save a copy of an
> earlier version, or restore a spreadsheet to an earlier version.

So if you have saved version with desired order you can restore it or copy from that, just go to File > Revert to > Browse all versions

Comment: thanks but I already added additional rows after I sorted, so it's all ruined...  It's so dumb that Apple wouldn't just have a way to have sorting as a translation for viewing.  There's no reason to make that modify the file, and they if there is a reason, they could make an "apply permanent sort" option or something... This is just unfortunately another example of Apple making ridiculously bad decisions.

Comment: It would be nice to know whether there is any spreadsheet program that implements sorting as you have envisioned. Then it can be decided whether bad decision is made by Apple or this is a worldwide conspiracy. Me wonders also - how should reverting to original order look like if you have added rows? For me it's quite clear that 'original order' doesn't include rows added and this can be achieved by using earlier version of file. If you haven't sorted again after adding rows then you can copy table in original form from earlier version and rows added in current version into new table.

Comment: well, what I was saying is sorting should be a non-destructive thing, simply a "view" where the contents are displayed in whatever desired order.  So adding a row would simply be adding to the end of the list, regardless of what the "view" is.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting works differently than filtering. Assuming sorting is one of the last few actions you have taken in that Numbers file and you have not quit the file after sorting, just press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (a few times if sorting was not the very last action) to take it back.

Comment: no.. I sorted long ago...  I can't undo it.  So sorting permanently alters the document?

Comment: Yes, I am afraid so.

Comment: that's so silly!!!  Silly Apple!!!!